# What way to add rightclick menu inside react-three/fiber <Canvas />?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, menu

I did experiement with "import useContextMenu from "react-use-context-menu";" but when not included directly inside the canvas tags then some buggs occure. I put it inside the div before the canvas and it works semi fine but sometimes it just pops up etc.
in the app.js

```
const [
        bindMenu,
        bindMenuItem,
        useContextTrigger,
        { data, coords, setVisible }
      ] = useContextMenu();
      const [bindTrigger] = useContextTrigger({
        collect: () => "Title"
      });
      const [clickedCmd, setClickedCmd] = useState();
      const hideMenu = () => setVisible(false);
```

in the return

```
<Menu
        bindMenu={bindMenu}
        data={data}
        bindMenuItem={bindMenuItem}
        coords={coords}
        setClickedCmd={setClickedCmd}
        hideMenu={hideMenu}
      />
```

Menu.js:

```
import React from "react";
import '../index.css';

const Menu = props => {
  const {
    bindMenu,
    data,
    bindMenuItem,
    coords,
    setClickedCmd,
    hideMenu
  } = props;

  const handleMenuItemClick = n => () => {
    setClickedCmd(n);
    hideMenu();
  };
  return (
    <div {...bindMenu} className="menu">
       <p
        {...bindMenuItem}
        onFocus={() => console.log("focused")}
        onClick={handleMenuItemClick("first")}
      >
        some stuff
      </p> 
      <p
        {...bindMenuItem}
        onFocus={() => console.log("focused")}
        onClick={handleMenuItemClick("first")}
      >
        some stuff
      </p> 
      <p
        {...bindMenuItem}
        onFocus={() => console.log("focused")}
        onClick={handleMenuItemClick("first")}
      >
       some stuff
      </p> 
      <p
        {...bindMenuItem}
        onFocus={() => console.log("focused")}
        onClick={handleMenuItemClick("first")}
      >
        some stuff
      </p>
      <hr />
      <p>
        <span>Click coords: {JSON.stringify(coords)}</span>
      </p>

      <hr />
     
    </div>
  );
};

export default Menu;
```

I tried using context-menu from https://github.com/cluk3/use-context-menu#readme
I was hoping for a right-click menu for navigation on a website in a react-three/fiber lib

Comment: can you provide a simple codesandbox please? It would be easier to help you